# Is there non obfuscated sours code of Google analitics.js?

Tags: javascript

When I add google analytics to web page it loads `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js` scipt. Is there non-minified version of this script to study it? Or even tutorial explaining how it works?

Comment: I don't think there is. You can find beautified versions of it but not the original unminified code https://github.com/LeZuse/ga-unobfuscated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put the minified code into a javascript formatter. For simplicity sake, lets use https://unminify.com/.

Grabbing the code from https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js and passing it through https://unminify.com/ yields us a lagre chunk of "unminified" code. Its still hard to read, since its using short and none-descriptive names, but it is somewhat readable.

Example of "unminifed" but still hard to read code:

```js
    var k = this,
        l = function(a, b) {
            a = a.split(".");
            var c = k;
            a[0] in c || "undefined" == typeof c.execScript || c.execScript("var " + a[0]);
            for (var d; a.length && (d = a.shift());) a.length || void 0 === b ? c = c[d] && c[d] !== Object.prototype[d] ? c[d] : c[d] = {} : c[d] = b
        };
    var m = function(a, b) {
            for (var c in b) b.hasOwnProperty(c) && (a[c] = b[c])
        },
        n = function(a) {
            for (var b in a)
                if (a.hasOwnProperty(b)) return !0;
            return !1
        };
    var q = /^(?:(?:https?|mailto|ftp):|[^:/?#]*(?:[/?#]|$))/i;
    var r = window,
        t = document,
        u = function(a, b) {
            t.addEventListener ? t.addEventListener(a, b, !1) : t.attachEvent && t.attachEvent("on" + a, b)
        };
```

Fiddle (the source is to large for SO): https://jsfiddle.net/s4bdL0y8/